# ENOENT Error while Building: 'no such file or directory, unlink' - How to resolve?

Tags: node.js, parcel, enoent

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'D:\Code\Web_Development\Java_Script_Notes\Asynchronous_JS\dist\index.html.
    at Object.unlinkSync (node:fs:1883:3)
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (D:\Code\Web_Development\Java_Script_Notes\Asynchronous_JS\node_modules\@parcel\fs\lib\index.
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
    at WriteStream.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'unlink',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'D:\\Code\\Web_Development\\Java_Script_Notes\\Asynchronous_JS\\dist\\index.html.9704.d'
}

Node.js v18.17.0`
```

I am encountering an issue while building my JavaScript project. During the build process, I'm getting an "ENOENT" error with the message "'no such file or directory, unlink'". The error specifically points to the file "index.html.9704.d" within the "dist" directory. I am using Node.js v18.17.0 and Parcel for the build.

I've double-checked the file paths and permissions, but I can't seem to figure out what's causing this issue. The "dist" directory does exist, but for some reason, the build process is unable to unlink the file mentioned in the error.